# Is DC to DC Step down module (buck module) correct for my learning/testing

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have a power supply MEAN WELL LRS-350-12 Switching Power Supply 350W 12V 29A Constant Current ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07BH1FTYP?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BH1FTYP)).

I am trying to learn some electronic circuitry using LEDs (and eventually build props using bullet pixels for christmas lighting).  I bought some low voltage LEDs for simple testing as shown here:  [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B077J2WJRS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077J2WJRS)

I would like to use one of the following for stepping down voltage/current (from my power supply above to the LEDs):

1. [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B078Q1624B](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078Q1624B)
2. [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JZ2GQJF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JZ2GQJF)

Both look similar to me and just wondering which of the above is suitable for my scenario and probably why?  Let me know if I am in wrong direction.

Comment: Besides the fact that this is Amazon, neither of those appear to supply 29 A nor 350 W. What's your actual need on these two parameters?

Comment: In spite of what that amazon listing claims, that is actually a 12v constant voltage power supply.  You can use it with a buck driver to drive individual LEDs, at least assuming the buck has a constant current mode and your LED forward voltages sum to less than 12v.

Comment: The seller says power supply is constant current. If that is true then your downstream devices will not be very happy, or the sellers do not understand what they are selling. But this is anyway more like "what to buy" question.

Comment: I bought the power supply for lighting up christmas lighting in the future.  However, for now, for basic circuitry testing, I don't quite need that level of amperage/watts.  I hardly would need those low voltage LEDs to light up.

Comment: Let me make it simple.  Can I light up an LED which would need 2V and 20mAh using above power supply and the buck?

Comment: I am trying to replicate something similar to what is shown here (using the devices I mentioned above):  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDkP97-BHXI